# Webform Validation Frameworks

Tags: asp.net, validation

I find that in most of my web projects a large majority of my time is spent validating user input both on the client-side and on the server-side.

I have worked with the ASP.NET form validation controls, but I have always found them to be cumbersome and never really work the way I intend them too.  So usually I end up rolling together my own validation manually.

In my current project there are about 450 fields for each record and those records end up getting updating on many different pages, so you can imagine that this requires a substantial time commitment to get all the validation correct.

Does anyone know of any good validation frameworks other than the built in ASP.NET form validation controls that will help me roll together validation quicker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

http://peterblum.com/DES/ProfessionalValidation.aspx

This is a great toolkit and an incredible value. I love what Scott Hanselman says..."Not an add-in but rather a complete re-imagining of the ASP.NET Validation Framework. There's a learning curve, but it will change the way you write pages. Also check out his Visual Security Security and Peter'sDatePackage. His documentation is legendary."

Comment: Looks interesting, but I hate products where you have to buy a license for each site you use it on.

Comment: set that aside for a few hours, download the trial and you will be blown away.